# Copy rows of same column to different index in a Pandas Dataframe. Duplicate data of one month to Another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I am trying to copy/replace data into a column of a dataframe. 
When the index is the same, I can easily copy it.
For Example:

```
sampledata['Total']=actualdata['Total']
```

above and below both work.

```
sampledata.loc[janStart:janEnd, 'Total'] = (sampledata.loc[0:755, 'Total']
```

But when I try to copy the data from either one data frame to another to different indexes. Or to a different index in the same dataframe, it doesn't work.
The following code doesn't works:

```
sampledata.loc[1417:2153, 'Total'] = sampledata.loc[0:743, 'Total']
```

I have also tried this:

```
actualdata.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
  #actualdata.index=sampledata.index
  #sampledata.ignore_index = True
  #actualdata.ignore_index = True
  #actualdata.reindex_like(actualdata)
sampledata.loc[1417:2153, 'Total'] = actualdata.loc[0:743, 'Total']
```

The purpose of this code is to copy the use of electrical consumption from one month to another. 
Any other methods that can be used are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to copy a `Series`, index must match.

A simple trick to get rid of the indexes of the copied Series is to extract its values actually converting it to an indexless array:

```
sampledata.loc[1417:2153, 'Total'] = sampledata.loc[0:736, 'Total'].values
```

The only requirement is that sizes shall match.